# Nested loop equivalent

Tags: haskell

I want to do a list of concatenations in Haskell.
I have [1,2,3] and [4,5,6]
and i want to produce [14,15,16,24,25,26,34,35,36].
I know I can use zipWith or sth, but how to do equivalent of:
foreach in first_array
   foreach in second_array

I guess I have to use map and half curried functions, but can't really make it alone :S

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use list comprehension to do it:

```
[x * 10 + y | x <- [1..3], y <- [4..6]]
```

In fact this is a direct translation of a nested loop, since the first one is the outer / slower index, and the second one is the faster / inner index.

Answer (score 17):

You can exploit the fact that lists are monads and use the **do notation**:

```
do
  a <- [1, 2, 3]
  b <- [4, 5, 6]
  return $ a * 10 + b
```

You can also exploit the fact that lists are applicative functors (assuming you have `Control.Applicative` imported):

```
(+) <$> (*10) <$> [1,2,3] <*> [4,5,6]
```

Both result in the following:

```
[14,15,16,24,25,26,34,35,36]
```

Comment: It produces `[a]`. What if I want `[[a]]`. Let's say I want to implement: `createImage :: Int -> int -> [[Color]]`?  i.e it takes `width` and `height`  and returns an image of size `width x height` , each pixel  `Color` is computed as `pixelColor i j height width`? How do I write the loops?

Comment: @Nawaz Easy! Use ranges and nested do-block: `createImage w h = do y <- [0..(h-1)]; return $ do x <- [0..(w-1)]; return (pixelColor w h x y)`. The compiler will optimize this into a tight loop.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. That's what I've used. I thought there is more idiomatic way of doing that. Like a higher order function or such.

Comment: One could argue that it's not exactly correct to use a monad for this task, since functor is enough: `createImage w h = fmap (\ y -> fmap (\ x -> pixelColor w h x y) [0..(w-1)]) [0..(h-1)]`. But in practice it doesn't matter, since the compiler will produce the same bytecode. So it's more of a matter of personal preferences and our community is not particularly strict about that.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to know that.

Comment: From your `fmap` example, I realized what we can write `fmap (pixelColor w h) [0..h-1] <*> [0..w-1]` as well, _provided_ `pixelColor` takes `y` followed by `x`: i.e `pixelColor w h y x`.

Comment: ah, `(pixelColor w h) <$> [0..h-1] <*> [0..w-1]` is even better! Wow! sometimes the code could shrink this much!

Comment: However, in my case, I want this: `(pixelColor w h) <$> reverse [0..h-1] <*> [0..w-1]` .. Still awesome!

Comment: Yes, but then you lose your original requirement of producing a 2d list :) BTW, there's no need for braces around pixelColor in your last snippet. Concerning code shrinking, prepare for many exciting surprises in Haskell. The power of abstractions it provides is just overwhelming :)

Comment: ah, yes. Completely forgot to check that. Haha. It seems we cannot shrink it anymore than what you suggested.

Answer (score 5):

If you really like seeing `for` in your code you can also do something like this:

```
for :: [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
for = flip map

nested :: [Integer]
nested = concat nested_list
  where nested_list =
          for [1, 2, 3] (\i ->
            for [4, 5, 6] (\j ->
              i * 10 + j
            )
          )
```

You could also look into [`for`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html#v%3afor) and [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor-Identity.html) for a more idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 2):

Nested loops correspond to nested uses of `map` or similar functions.  First approximation:

```
notThereYet :: [[Integer]]
notThereYet = map (\x -> map (\y -> x*10 + y) [4, 5, 6]) [1, 2, 3]
```

That gives you nested lists, which you can eliminate in two ways.  One is to use the `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` function:

```
solution1 :: [Integer]
solution1 = concat (map (\x -> map (\y -> x*10 + y) [4, 5, 6]) [1, 2, 3])
```

Another is to use this built-in function:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap f xs = concat (map f xs)
```

Using that:

```
solution2 :: [Integer]
solution2 = concatMap (\x -> map (\y -> x*10 + y) [4, 5, 6]) [1, 2, 3]
```

Other people have mentioned list comprehensions and the list monad, but those really bottom down to nested uses of `concatMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `do` notation and the list comprehension have been said already. The only other option I know is via the `liftM2` combinator from `Control.Monad`. Which is the exact same thing as the previous two.

```
liftM2 (\a b -> a * 10 + b) [1..3] [4..6]
```

Comment: ... only shorter (than all but first). :) nicccce!

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of the concatenation of two lists of integers is this:

```
concatInt [] xs = xs
concatInt xs [] = xs
concatInt xs ys = [join x y | x <- xs , y <- ys ]
    where
    join x y = firstPart + secondPart
      where
      firstPart = x *  10 ^ lengthSecondPart
      lengthSecondPart = 1 + (truncate $ logBase 10 (fromIntegral y))
      secondPart = y
```

Example: concatInt [1,2,3] [4,5,6] == [14,15,16,24,25,26,34,35,36]

More complex example:
concatInt [0,2,10,1,100,200] [24,2,999,44,3] == [24,2,999,44,3,224,22,2999,244,23,1024,102,10999,1044,103,124,12,1999,144,13,10024,1002,100999,10044,1003,20024,2002,200999,20044,2003]